# The smartest way to redirect in django without creating view

Tags: django, redirect

The task is simple:

```
If user visits site root then:
    if user is authenticated then:
        redirect to /dashboard/
    else:
        redirect to settings.LOGIN_URL
```

There are many ways to implement that, but I wonder if there is such way in which I do need to use **only** urls.py.

I found a solution with RedirectView `login_required(RedirectView.as_view(url=my_url))`, however then I can only write static my_url instead of reverse(), which is not flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reverse_lazy` (Django 1.4) in you url configuration, like so:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url, patterns
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import redirect

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/$', lambda request: return redirect(reverse_lazy('url_name')),
)
```

Another possibility is to define `LOGIN_URL` using `reverse_lazy`, so you could continue to use `settings.LOGIN_URL` in your redirects.

<sub>Code is untested, might have a typo somewhere.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You just need to mixin LoginRequired to your view. You can find an example of the mixin here:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2442/

Then where you define that view, you just do:

```
class RedirectView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    ....
```

Or whatever Class Based View you're inheriting from. Hope that helps!